# How to recover data from a LVM volume on a mdadm software raid 1 array?

Tags: lvm, raid

I had used Ubuntu 12.04 to build a mdadm software raid 1 array from 2 harddisks, and then I created a LVM on this array and used this LVM to install my Ubuntu 12.04 system on it (I still have a boot partition outside the LVM).

Recently, my system could not boot any more (I guess the 5 years harddisks may be too old and have some problems). I now boot my system from an Ubuntu 16.04 live CD but I could not see the data in my LVM volume.

Could anyone guide me the procedures to view my data in the LVM volume? Thanks for any suggestion.

EDIT :
In fact, the LVM is built on 2 mdadm software raid 1 arrays. The structure is listed below :

```
/dev/sda5 + /dev/sdb5 -> A1 (1st raid 1 array)
/dev/sda6 + /dev/sdb6 -> A2 (2nd raid 1 array)
A1 + A2 -> LV1 (LVM volume built on 2 raid 1 arrays)
```

When I boot my computer using Ubuntu 16.04 live CD, the output for the following commands is :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvscan
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo pvscan
  No matching physical volumes found
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

It seems that I could not find my LVM volume.

What could I do to fix this problem? Any comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install mdadm (raid deamon) which is not present by default on the live Cd. Then you can perform the "assemble scan operation"

```
sudo apt-get install mdadm -y 
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```

Then perform lvscan/vgscan

```
sudo vgscan
sudo lvscan
```

Then use `sudo fdisk -l | grep dev` to find your list of logical volumes

Then perform the fcsk with command like

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/mapper/NAME_OF_THE_LOGICAL_VOLUME
```

Regards,

Emmanuel

Comment: Tested OK on my system. In addition, I use `sudo vgchange -ay NAME_OF_THE_VOLUME_GROUP` to activate my logical volume.